# application or component to aid in raw material utilization

Tags: simulation, production

problem: I have a physical production process that takes one bulk input and converts it to many individual jobs.  The output of each job is numerous individual pieces.  It is possible during the process to split the bulk input between two different jobs (at the same time) and each job my be able to produce 1 to n individual pieces.
I am looking for a way to model this interaction and vary the number of pieces (as well as other items) to simulate production and evaluate the results.

Does anyone have any ideas of a tool or components (open source preferred) that might help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with Python, I recommend you try my own [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org) framework. It can definitely handle the kind of simulation you want. [There are tutorials available](http://docs.garlicsim.org/intro/index.html) which will teach you the basics of GarlicSim in 30 minutes. I'll be happy to help you build your simulation package, just say hello on the [mailing list](http://docs.garlicsim.org/misc/mailing-lists.html) and I'll guide you from there.